# How to show the current time in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, timezone

So I am doing backend lessons on FreeCodeCamp. And in the Chain Middleware to Create a Time Server challenge (the link to the challenge: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/apis-and-microservices/basic-node-and-express/chain-middleware-to-create-a-time-server), I could not show the current time as it said on the test.
my code:

```
app.get('/now',function(req,res,next){
  req.time = new Date().toString()
  next()
},function(req,res){
  res.send({time:req.time})
})
```

the output shows the UTC time : {"time":"Fri Jun 12 2020 15:30:16 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)"}

I was expecting to see the GMT+6.00 time as I live in Bangladesh. Can anyone help me how to do that

Comment: That seems right...? It looks like you successfully completed the challenge that you linked to. Do you want the current time expressed in a specific time zone?

Comment: What are you ***expecting*** to see?

Comment: @apsillers I was expecting to see the local time which is GMT+6 (as I live in bangladesh). 
By the way guys, I tried entering the same code again and somehow it worked. I don't know how, as the code was not passing the tests. But it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understood properly the question, but maybe you're looking for `Date.now()` ? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)

Comment: I was expecting to see the local time which is GMT+6 (as I live in bangladesh). By the way guys, I tried entering the same code again and somehow it worked. I don't know how, as the code was not passing the tests. But it worked